# How do I use Laravel models to access existing database tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an old application that I wrote using native PHP. Now I am trying to implement new functionality using Laravel 4... and I am lost..
What I first need to do is to get the results from this select statement onto a page:

```
$sql = "SELECT item.item_id, reg_number, serial_1, serial_2, serial_3, item_type, item_material, item_loc, addit_info.* 
                FROM items
                JOIN addit_info on items.item_id = addit_info.item_id
                WHERE items.status = 's'
                ORDER BY status_changed DESC LIMIT 0 , 100;";
```

The schema of the tables is:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`items`(`item_id`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
reg_number`char(9) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
reg_type`char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
make_id`tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,`
model`varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
main_color`varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
other_color`varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
serial_1`varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
serial_2`varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
serial_3`varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
item_type`char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
item_material`char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
status`char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
status_changed`timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`
price`float(6,2) unsigned NOT NULL,`
description`varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
item_loc`varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY`reg_number`(`reg_number`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=476` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addit_info` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_date1` date NOT NULL,
  `event_from` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `more_info` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `event_date2` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`event_date1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

I don't know what my model(s) should look like. I suppose I will not be able to use the Eloquent functionality, but instead will have to write queries with the query builder. But still, I do not know where to put my query. Should it be in a model that handles all queries that I would like to use?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking 2 things at the same time, but I'll focus on the question in the title "How do I use Laravel models to access existing database tables?".

I'm pretty sure you can use Eloquent with your old database structure. Three important things about Eloquent in this case:

1. Eloquent will pluralize your model name, and snake case it to get the table name (your model name should be fine for this one).
2. Eloquent defaults to `id` column as the primary key. Need to change to `item_id`.
3. `$timestamps` is enabled by default, which means that it will try to look for `created_at` and `updated_at` columns. We need to disable it.

So you will need to override #2 and #3 above to make your Eloquent model work, try this:

**models/Item.php:**

```
class Item extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'items';
    protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    // ...
}
```

As for your second (hidden question), you should be able to look up Laravel docs to figure out how to do [joins](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins) or [relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) easily.